# Inserting more than one data field in a sorted data structure

Tags: data-structures

What is the best data structure to use when you need to insert more than 1 (like 10) data fields in a node and have the nodes to be stored in the ascending order of their key?

Answer (score 0):

In general, inserts element need 3 steps:

1. locate where to insert
2. insert it
3. adjust data structure if needs

If the inserting elements have **regularity**(like all elements equals, It will save `1. locate where to insert` time in linked list), but time complexity still `O(n)`.

If the inserting elements have **no regularity**, it random enough. There is no difference between inserting one and insert batch.

So in one word, there is **no special data structure** for batch inserting. but you can improve `Constant Time Complexity` in some special conditions.

**PS: common sorted data structure is balanced binary tree, spends `O(logn)` time complexity when updating**